# onchange event in magento 2

Tags: php, jquery, magento, magento2

I am using magento 2.1.0, i am new to magento, so i am not able to get the actual result.

I have created this block:

```
public function serviceArea() { 
    return $this->getArea1('2');
}

public function getArea1($city_id) {
    return $this->areaModel->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('city_id',$city_id);

}
```

and I am calling like this:

```
$areaCollection = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('XXXX\Vac   \Block\Vac')->serviceArea();
print_r($areaCollection->getData());
```

I am getting output like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [area_id] => 1 [area] => banashankari [city_id] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [area_id] => 2 [area] => madiwala [city_id] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [area_id] => 3 [area] => btm layout [city_id] => 2 ) )
```

now, i want this out for my onchange process, like when i change city  in dropdown , my area will change accordingly.

for that. I write script:

```
<script>
    require(['jquery'], function(jQuery) {
        jQuery('#city').on('change', function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]).'Vac/area/index/'; ?>",
                // url: "getAjaxUrl()",
                data: {city_id: jQuery("#city").val()},
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery('#area').html(data['html']);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

in script, I gave the url of my controller. but I don't know what to do there, or I have to modify the script. please help.

Comment: You need to set proper responce from the controller and based on that responce, you need to do code in sucess action of Jquery to display that things in dropdown.

Comment: @sam: Do you got the answer?

Comment: @MujeebuRahman : yes mujeebu, i got the answer,  just have to write the execute function in controller to by using the loop

Answer (score 0):

Check all below mentioned files exist in your shipping extension.

```
view/
└── frontend
    ├── layout
    │   ├── checkout_cart_index.xml
    │   └── checkout_index_index.xml
    └── web
        └── js
            ├── model
            │   ├── shipping-rates-validation-rules.js
            │   └── shipping-rates-validator.js
            └── view
                └── shipping-rates-validation.js
```